# What happens internally in an OS, when opening a hyperlink from within a pdf document?

Tags: pdf, hyperlink, operating-system, system-calls

What happens on an OS level when I open a pdf file with a documet reader and the pdf file contains a link and I click on it? 
Somehow my webbrowser pops up and displays the link's content.

What is the mechanism behind this scenario?

Is the document reader performing a *system call* and the OS opens the webbrowser?

I couldn't find useful answers so far. Thanks for all answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concept of an Operating System has become fuzzy.  Fortunately, for the most part the concept of a kernel -- the thing that interprets system calls -- hasn't fallen down this hole.
A kernel performs relatively low-level operations; such as assigning and revoking RAM to and from address spaces, satisfying hardware interrupt requests, safely transferring data from external devices into RAM....  the list goes on, but is marked by tight definitions and short scope.

The response to an input gesture ( such as a mouse click, or if you are on windows a frantic collection of left and right clicky  motions until something happens ) is in the domain of responsibility above the kernel.   Often, people of a certain age insist that the operating system ends at the kernel.

From the application that you are running's point of view, the click-y gestures indicates to it that it should:

> 1. Look at the sort of object that is in the vicinity of the pointer.
> 2. If that object is a video, maybe it should play, or stop playing that video.
> 3. If that object is a page/paragraph reference, maybe it should jump to that location.
> 4. If that object is an URL (Universal Resource Locator), it should invoke some sort of *URL resolution framework* to resolve the clicky.

[4] is probably what happens in your case, and the mechanism to resolve this URL could involve all manner of operating system services, including starting new processes, loading shells within them, reading configuration files, ad nausia.

These frameworks live in a bit of a grey area in operating systems; they aim to implement generic concepts using the underlying implementation to best effect. This is something much easier said than done.   Many feel that the relationship between the vendor,framework,programmer is rooted in the relation between the pusher,drug,user.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful and kind answer mevets. 
I see, so a layer above the OS handles the URL. 
How can the pdf reader have the rights to open the web browser? Or are there any rights needed at all? Sorry, if this is a silly question, just trying to understand the concept qualitatively.

Comment: Your rights may be limited in terms of how much memory, cpu, # processes, packet rate and the like, but typically ports (protocols) are managed on the in-bound, not the out bound.   Some systems go a bit further, running processes in a sandbox which enforce more finely grained access controls; for example the base permission system might permit any program you run to read your contacts, but a sandbox might be configured to add protections against nosy programs.    Start a shell and try some.